# Как передать значение из активити в фрагмент

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Есть активити которое вызывает фрагменты через интефейс. И нужно при создании екземпляра фрагмента передать ему значение. Я использовал конструктор в Фрагменте, но Андроид Студия говорит что так делать нельзя. Вообщем вопрос как передать из активити в Фрагмент значение?

Answer (score 6):

В активити экземпляру фрагмента через .setArguments передавать свой Bundle с параметрами

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

А в самом фрагменте получить переданный Bundle

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment