# Передача данных из Activity в Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Нужно передать текст из активности во фрагмент.
Под этот метод вызова

```
    public void NewsClick(View view)
    { 
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, UniversalListFragment.newInstance("notes.json")).commit();
    }
```

сделал так, но ничего не происходит.
Вот код фрагмента

```
     private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "notes.json";
     public static UniversalListFragment newInstance(String name) 
     {
        UniversalListFragment fragment = new UniversalListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TAG_FRAGMENT, name);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Поясните как передать по этому методу [Как передать значение из активити в фрагмент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014/) , нужно просто вместо fragment.setArguments(bundle); написать UniversalListFragment.setArguments(bundle); . А NewsClick оставить как есть? и Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); в oncreate засунуть

Код фрагмента

```
public class UniversalListFragment extends Fragment {




private static final String NOTE_TITLE = "title" ;
private static final String NOTE_CONTENT = "content" ;
private JSONAdapter noteAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLLM;
private JSON note;
private JSONObject jsonObject;
private JSONArray jsonArray;
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "notes.json";
public static UniversalListFragment newInstance(String name)
{
    UniversalListFragment fragment = new UniversalListFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TAG_FRAGMENT, name);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rv = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    //recyclerview///
    noteAdapter = new JSONAdapter();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rv.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));


    mLLM = new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLLM);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    try {
        loadNotes();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar!= null) {
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.start_service);
    }
    return rv;
}

private void loadNotes() throws JSONException {
    jsonArray = new JSONArray(getJSONString());
    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        note = new JSON(jsonObject.getString(NOTE_TITLE),  jsonObject.getString(NOTE_CONTENT));
        noteAdapter.addNote(note);

    }
    noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}



private String getJSONString(){

    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open(TAG_FRAGMENT); // go to main/asset directory to see notes.json

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

}

Comment: Ничего это фрагмент не показывается или текст не приходит в него?

Comment: доставайте аргументы в конструкторе фрагмента: `String txt = getArguments().getString(TAG_FRAGMENT);`

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich,  может коммент в ответы закинете?

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich в конструкторе фрагмента никаких аргументов еще нет

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , фрагмент показывает значение по умолчанию

Comment: @joni, значит вы не там или не так вытаскиваете значение. Приведите код получения строки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , а сам метод правильный ? сейчас дополню

Comment: @joni, вы в коде вообще даже не пытаетесь же из аргументов строку вашу достать....

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , подскажите как достать

Comment: @joni `String strFromArgs = getArguments().getString("notes.json", "defaultValue");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо отображать во фрагменте различные данные в зависимости от заданных параметров, то код фрагмента должен быть следующим:

```
        private static final String NOTE_TITLE = "title" ;
    private static final String NOTE_CONTENT = "content" ;
    private final String TAG_FRAGMENT = "tag_fragment";
    private JSONAdapter noteAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLLM;
    private JSON note;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;
    private String mJson;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View rv = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        //recyclerview///
        noteAdapter = new JSONAdapter();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rv.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));


        mLLM = new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLLM);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
        try {
            loadNotes();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar!= null) {
            actionBar.setTitle(R.string.start_service);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    private void loadNotes() throws JSONException {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(getJSONString());
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            note = new JSON(jsonObject.getString(NOTE_TITLE),  jsonObject.getString(NOTE_CONTENT));
            noteAdapter.addNote(note);

        }
        noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private String getJSONString(){

        if(getArguments() != null){
            mJson = getArguments().getString(TAG_FRAGMENT);
        }

        if(mJson == null || mJson.isEmpty() || mJson.equals("")) return null;

        String json = null;

        try {

            InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open(mJson); // go to main/asset directory to see notes.json

            int size = is.available();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            is.read(buffer);

            is.close();

            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```

код вызова фрагмента :

```
public void NewsClick(View view)
{ 
     Bundle mArg = new Bundle();
     mArg.putString("tag_fragment", youData);
     Fragment mFrg = new UniversalListFragment();
     mFrg.setArguments(mArg);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, mFrg).commit();
}
```

где youData - данные, которые будут получены фрагментом;

Comment: Да я уже много чего перепробовал оказалась ошибка в InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open() // он открывает первый файл при любом значении

Comment: Вы не в курсе как исправить?

Comment: Так в Вашем варианте фрагмента он и будет всегда читать один и тот же файл InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open(TAG_FRAGMENT) так как TAG_Fragment всегда будет равно "notes.json". В предложенном мной варианте Вы через аргумент передадите во фрагмент наименование требуемого файла из assets в дальнейшем считаете его.

Comment: @m-gdemin, в чем дело setString горит красным

Comment: или там putString?

Answer (score -3):

Вы передаете переменную напрямую в функцию получения инстанса фрагмента, но ни где ее не используете.

Для того, чтобы получить ваши данные при такой системе вызова, используйте код:

```
public YouFragment extends Fragment{

public static YouFragment mInstance;

private String mYouText;

public static YouFtagment getInstance(String youText){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new YouFragment();
    }
    mInstance.mYouText = youText;
    return mInstance;
}
```

Передаваемые Вами данные станут доступны в переменной mYouString.

Comment: С таким кодом вы сразу получите утечку, т.к. сборщик мусора не сможет очистить память, которая будет выделена для фрагмента.

Comment: Поясните как передать по этому методу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014/ , нужно просто вместо fragment.setArguments(bundle); написать UniversalListFragment.setArguments(bundle); . А NewsClick оставить как есть? и Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); в oncreate засунуть

Comment: К вопросу утечки памяти - фрагмент будет в любом случае висеть в FragmentManager и до того момента пока будет жива активность сборщик мусора его не тронет. Для пущей верности можно добавить обнуление инстанса в onDestroy().

Comment: а два фрагмента с разными youText создать нельзя? viewPager, там... или, например, создать этот же фрагмент из другой активити, а потом вернуться на предыдущую... в общем, ужасно.

Comment: Судя по представленному коду фрагмента, он всегда будет выводить один и тот же текст из жестко заданного файла в Assets. Если нужна именно такая функциональность, то в создании инстанса на фрагмент вообще нет ни какой необходимость достаточно просто на процедуру нажатия повесить new UniversalListFragment вместо UniversalListFragment.newInstance(..)