# Андроид. Как передать массив с помощью Parcelable parcel

Tags: java, android, массивы

Для передачи строки из активити в фрагмент создал Класс class MyObject implements Parcelable. 
Строки отлично передаются, а вот с массивом возникает ошибка
верней подчеркивает скобки readArray(). Я так понял в скобки нужно что-то написать или может вообще не readArray() нужно использовать

Внизу весь код

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {

public String paramBuk;
public String[] paramImya;




public MyObject(String paramBuk, String[]  paramImya) {
    this.paramBuk = paramBuk;
    this.paramImya = paramImya;

}

private MyObject(Parcel parcel) {  // Создание объекта через Parcel
    paramBuk = parcel.readString();
    paramImya = parcel.readArray();

}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {      //Упаковывание объекта в Parcel
    parcel.writeString(paramBuk);
    parcel.writeArray(paramImya);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {   // Статический метод с помощью которого создаем обьект
    public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyObject(in);
    }

    public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyObject[size];
    }
};
}
```

public String paramBuk; - отлично работает, принимает данные и передает

А вот с public String[] paramImya; что-то не так, подчеркивает именно скобки readArray()

Comment: я не знаю, ради какой цели пишется этот огромный костыль, но по-человечески передаются данные из активити во фрагмент [вот так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чтения из `parcel` можно использовать команду:

```
paramImya = parcel.createStringArray();
```

А можно наверное более быстрый метод, в котором нужно заранее знать размер  `N`массива `paramImya` :

```
paramImya = new String[N];
parcel.readStringArray(paramImya);
```

И в `paramImya` будут храниться считанные значения.

В [исходниках](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.1.2_r1-robolectric-0/android/os/Parcel.java#Parcel.createStringArray%28%29) видно, что есть еще метод `readStringArray()`, который почему-то не указан в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArray()). Можете попытаться использовать его следующим образом:

```
paramImya = parcel.readStringArray();
```

Ну a записать данные в `parcel` можно командой:

```
parcel.writeStringArray(paramImya);
```

Comment: Спасибо я уже нашел решение методом тыка)) Но все правильно надо было через readStringArray