# Как получить из фрагмента доступ к активити?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Ребят нужна помощь ... в MainActivity получаю данные о моем местоположении ... как мне эти данные передать во фрагмент или как во  фрагменте достать эти данные из активти  для дальнейшого использовния??сойдет любой пример

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014/Как-передать-значение-из-активити-в-фрагмент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из фрагмента можно получить соотвествуюющуую актвити вызвав метод `getActivity()`. В этом активити создайте метод для получения этих координат и вызовите его после `getActivity()`. Вот [пример](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/df319142e50c5a6186f8e9838531fe34455df692/Fragments/Dynamic/src/com/commonsware/android/dfrag/ContentFragment.java).

Comment: можете показать пример этого ?получение любого метода посредствм getActivity

Comment: Добавил пример.