# получение значений из адаптера в фрагмент

Tags: android, массивы, android-fragment, adapter

Создал RecyclerView в адаптере добавил элементы,которые изображены на фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Adapter

```
public class ProcessorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProcessorAdapter.ViewHolder> {
View view = null;
private int[] mDataset;
private ArrayList<Processor> dataSet;
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title,prioritet,time,ram;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        prioritet= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.prioritet);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        ram = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ram);
    }
}
public ProcessorAdapter(int[] dataset1) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}
@Override
public ProcessorAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
     view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.processor_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
    return vh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position]));
    int prioritett = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10 - 1 + 1);
    holder.prioritet.setText(String.valueOf(prioritett));
    int timer   = 6 + rnd.nextInt(22 - 6 + 1);
    holder.time.setText(String.valueOf(timer));
    int ramm  = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
    holder.ram.setText(String.valueOf(ramm));
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
```

}

> Фрагмент

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    int[] myDataset = getDataSet();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    // создаем адаптер
    mAdapter = new ProcessorAdapter(myDataset,myDataset1);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}
private int[] getDataSet() {
    int bundle= getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("P");
   int[] mDataSet = new int[bundle];
    for (int i = 0; i < bundle; i++) {
        mDataSet[i] = i;
    }
    return mDataSet;
}
```

}
Как видно в коде ,в адаптаре значение title я получаю `holder.title.setText(String.valueOf(mDataset[position]));`
И в фрагменте получаю данные и вывожу через цикл

```
int[] mDataSet1 = new int[bundle];
    for (int i = 0; i < bundle; i++) {
        mDataSet1[i] = i;
    }
```

Другие значение например RAM я в адаптаре рандома задаю значения

```
int ramm  = 100 + rnd.nextInt(1000 - 100 + 1);
    holder.ram.setText(String.valueOf(ramm));
```

И как видно оно правильно выводит рандомгые числа.
Но тут у меня возникла проблема,которая заключается в том ,как эти значения отправить в фрагмент в массив,например как в title.
Чтоб в фрагменте получилось массив ram[499,506].И я мог дальше сортировать или работать с этими данными в фрагменте.
Надеюсь доступно объяснил в чем заключается проблема.

Comment: то, что вы пытаетесь сделать неприемлемо в разработке, адаптер не предназначен для генерации данных, только для их отображения. Генерируйте ваш массив случайных чисел в фрагменте и делайте с ним, что хотите. Передавайте этот массив в адаптер для отображения, так же как и названия, налучшим вариантом будет генерировать эти данные в тот же массив, что и названия (многомерный массив), чтобы данные были связаны — это решит множество проблем, как сортировка. В реальной практике динамические структуры как массивы вообще не используются — данные хранятся в БД или в файле , как JSON, XML

Comment: хорошо, тогда как передать в адаптер значения из фрагмента

Comment: так же, как вы передаете названия процессоров - через конструктор адаптера

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял философию элементов View, то они предназначены для отображения информации, но никак не для длительного хранения. Но если всё-таки очень хочется, то ничто не мешает создать невидимый TextView и заполнить его вашими данными.

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/hidden_array"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: не то что нужно

Comment: кажется я вас понял. Вы из активности хотите передать данные (массив) в фрагмент. Для таких целей можете использовать Bundle. Вот здесь рассмотрен ваш вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455014/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: мне нужно из адаптера (код выше)получить значения в фрагмент.Потому что на данный момент в фрагменте я могу изменять только title

Comment: не знаю чем помочь, по идее адаптер не предназначен для генерации новых данных, возможно стоит вынести куда-то ещё.

Answer (score 0):

что если просто создать статистический массив например в том же фрагменте:

```
public static int[] mDataset;
```

и дальше уже инициализировать и наполнять его где угодно.

Еще лучше создать отдельный класс `StaticConstants.java` например и в нем хранить все эти данные.