# Ошибка инициализации textEdit при вызове функции фрагмента из активити

Tags: java, android, kotlin

При выполнении функции из активити не успевает пройти инициализация полей фрагмента. Функция вызывается из пункта меню (в тулбаре)

```
val myFragment = FirstFragment()
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, myFragment , "MyFragment")
            .commit()
                
        myFragment.date1.setText("30.04.2018")
```

Comment: Это делается не так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455019/11515

Answer (score 0):

Как сказано в комментарии под твоим вопрос, нужно при передаче данных между activity и fragment стоит положить данные в bundle, а там уже в методе OnViewCreated(что бы гарантировать что view создастся) достать и вставить в нужное тебе поле, приведу пример

Код во фрагменте

```
  companion object {
        private const val DATA = "data"

        fun newInstance(data: String): Fragment = FirstFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(DATA to data)
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        requireArguments().getString(DATA)?.let { data ->
            //to do
        }
    }
```

код во активити

```
val myFragment = FirstFragment.newInstance(data)
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, myFragment , "MyFragment")
            .commit()
```

Comment: по сути мне надо такую команду выполнить  `requireArguments().getString(DATA)?.let { _ ->
                date1.setText("30.04.2018") }`   Но ваш код не предполагает заполнение полей?

Comment: в итоге решил через Callback